# jQuery addClass not working on DOM fired from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I have a menu HTML code that is injected into the DOM via a jQuery function, i.e.

```
$.get("/clients/nav_menu.html", function(data) {
    $("nav").html(data);
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu(); //menu plugin for Bootstrap
});
```

However, after changing the loading of menu to the above script, the Bootstrap distribution package (sb-admin-2) that came with the below lines of code failed during load only (resize continues to work fine) for the code marked (*******) below:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
        topOffset = 50;
        width = (this.window.innerWidth > 0) ? this.window.innerWidth : this.screen.width;
        if (width < 768) {
            $('div.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse'); // *******
            topOffset = 100;
        } else {
            $('div.navbar-collapse').removeClass('collapse');
        }

        height = ((this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height) - 1;
        height = height - topOffset;
        if (height < 1) height = 1;
        if (height > topOffset) {
            $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
        }
    });

    var url = window.location;
    var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
    if (element.is('li')) {
        element.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

The piece of code marked (*******) above fires during load and resize, and div.navbar-collapse resides in the menu HTML code that was injected as mentioned above. I just don't understand why it fails to modify the DOM element during load, but once I resize the screen width, the class 'collapse' gets added to the div.

What I've tried:

- made sure that each time I reload the page, the screen size is less than 768px - didn't work;
- bringing the code marked (*******) to the end of all my js scripts - didn't work;
- bringing the code marked (*******) into the $.get callback right after the menu was loaded - didn't work;

Comment: Not an answer to your question but have you tried letting bootstrap handle the collapsing of the navbar for you, or perhaps a media query in your CSS?

Comment: The handling of the collapsing of the navbar works fine until I moved the menu code outside of my HTML script and instead load it via jQuery

Comment: But no - I haven't tried letting bootstrap handle or did any media query. Not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: What caused you to move the navbar HTML out of the page?

Comment: Because I have multiple pages that include the navbar, I don't want to be editing every page when I need to update certain items in the navbar.